# Key-Value Observing an NSMutableArray within an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, key-value-observing

Key-Value Observing the to-many relationship of an `NSMutableArray` seems like a good technique for [automatically updating a tableview](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/11/using-kvo-for-table-updates.html) that has a single section and many rows. However, my table view is grouped and more naturally fits having an array, `sections`, with each object within being an array containing the rows for that section. Is there any way for me to use KVO to observe the `row` arrays within the `sections` array when the number of sections is dynamic?

Ultimately, I wanted to achieve something similar to the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods without having to use Core Data:

`- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type`

`- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)object
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath`

Comment: I think you have to add KVO to the parent array (sections) then add KVO to each child array inserted/removed from that array as they are added/removed.

Comment: `NSArray`s don't post KVO notices for insertions and deletions. You should look into using an array controller.

Comment: @nielsbot I'm not super familiar with KVO for to-many relationships, but to do observe a to-many relationship you have to specifically named methods for KVO to work, i.e. for an array named `items` you have to use `insertObject:inItemsAtIndex:` (and several others). This is the only example I've found: https://github.com/jlamarche/Old-Blog-Code/blob/master/KVOTables/Classes/RootViewController.m

Comment: @JoshCaswell This is for iOS so I can't use an `NSArrayController`, but I know I can observe the to-many relationship of the `NSArray` as discussed in this blog post http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/11/using-kvo-for-table-updates.html

Comment: Assuming the array you want to observe is a property of some object, mutating that property via the array returned by `-mutableArrayValueForKey:` will post KVO notifications for that property. (If that makes sense)